# Line breaks in a plaint text email?

Tags: html, email, html-email, plaintext

I'm making a plain text email, in the head I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8">
```

I'm trying to line break content with

```
\n
```

Also with

```
\r\n
```

But nothing breaks the line.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `<br>`, or `%0D%0A`?

Comment: <br> in plain text?

Comment: %0D%0A does not work.

Comment: Can you share more of your code.  One common issue is forgetting to use double quotes when trying to use `\r\n`

Comment: chrisz - it's just plain text, so any text at all

Comment: Then post the code you use to create the email.

Comment: The problem is most likely that your email is HTML formatted and not plain text. You need to provide a [mcve] showing how you are constructing the entire email (including SMTP headers).

Comment: If you checking in Outlook, it shows a message at times just like when the images are blocked. Click on it to see the line breaks from the document you sent. What are you using to create the text document? Just plain notepad? What platform are you using to send it thru?

Answer (score -2):

here is a HTML tag `<br>` for line breaking and you can also break lines by CSS and JavaScript